# Recursion tree for recursive equation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, asymptotic-complexity

I have this recursive equation:
T(n) =  T(n/2) + T(n/5) + T(n/9) + Θ(n)

I draw my recursion tree like this:

```
          cn
     /     |     \
   n/2    n/5    n/9
  / | \  / | \  / | \
  ..................
```

The tree has log(n) + 1 levels, each level has 3 times more nodes than the level above, and subproblem sizes decrease by a factor of 2 each time. Now this is how I see the total cost is:

[image]

I forgot to put this: Is my solution correct?

Comment: There is no actual question here.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Where did you get the (3 / 2) term from?

Comment: @templatetypedef So I think the longest path is n -> n/2 -> n/4... 
So the number nodes at depth i is 3^i, and each node at depth i, has a cost of c(n / (2^i)). So the total cost is 3^i * c(n / (2^i)), or (3/2)^i * cn

Comment: Hint: the time complexity's upper bound is given by the depth of the *longest* branch of the recursion tree.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog which is n/2 right?

Comment: @PTN correct. Now think about what the "effective" recurrence relation would be, i.e. a simpler one which gives the same upper bound.

Comment: @PTN I did not downvote this. Just put a comment. Although I do find it hilarious that you downvoted one of my questions because you thought I downvoted yours. Would appreciate it if you removed your downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the slightly more general relation:

[image]

Where `f(n)` is some function, e.g. `cn`.

---

If we re-substitute this relation into itself, i.e. each of the recursive calls, the next layer of recursive calls produced will have its parameter multiplied by the corresponding factor:

[image]

If we continue, the pattern is given by this expression:

[image]

... i.e. a [Trinomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion). The coefficients of each `T` term is given by the trinomial coefficients, and the argument by the different powers of `λμν`:

[image]

As you can see from the expansion, the `f`-terms are **one level of recursion** behind the `T`-terms. So, the sum of all `f`-terms, taking into consideration that they must be *accumulated* unlike the `T`-terms:

[image]

All of the above can be proven by *induction*, and are generalizable to *any* number of recursive calls.

---

When do we terminate, i.e. get rid of the `T`-terms? As I said in my comment, when recursion reaches the end of the longest path. This is given by considering the slowest decreasing term (as you correctly deduced):

[image]

> Thus the time complexity function's tightest closed-form bound is
>   given by:
>
> [image]

This is very easy to evaluate if `f(n)` is some power of `n`.

---

For the example, `f(n) = Θ(n), α = β = γ = 1, λ = 2, μ = 5, ν = 9`. Thus:

[image]

The term inside the brackets is *exactly* the trinomial expansion from earlier. Thus:

[image]

Since `τ < 1`, the exponential term vanishes. Therefore `T(n) = O(n)`.

Numerical tests to confirm this:

```
n         T(n)
-----------------------------
10        21.86111111
100       328.1442901
1000      3967.333431
10000     44150.87621
100000    471262.9357
1000000   4910520.041
10000000  50415530.84
```

**log-log** plot of `T(n)` against `n`:

[image]

The gradient is `1.054 ± 0.01166`, which is very close to the theoretical value of `1`, thus strongly supporting the result of `T(n) = O(n)`.